# Decode SimplePing response packet in Swift

Tags: swift, networking, ping, cfnetwork

I am using [SimplePing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html) sample from Apple to ping to a host which successfully received a response from the framework delegate

```
 func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing!, didReceivePingResponsePacket packet: NSData!)
```

Which I am struggled to find the way to to decode the packet data (e.g. get the host name, ip)

I know that it's something about CFNetwork but I just can't find the right way to read the data, hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone stumble upon this topic in pesent, like me.
Host name or ip address can be found in pinger property. If that is what you looking for.

Example:

```
func simplePing(_ pinger: SimplePing, didReceivePingResponsePacket packet: Data, sequenceNumber: UInt16) {
    print("Host: \(pinger.hostName)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample provides a method called icmpInPacket: that returns a broken-out struct.  Use that.  :-)

Comment: Yea I did, but the icmpInPacket method only returns a icmp header which has code, checksum, identifier and the sequenceNumber. All I need is the IP address of the Packet origin (liked what you get from terminal) , Is there a way that I can get it?